# Gluteus Medius doesn't feel like it is doing the work?

Tags: exercise, stretching, glutes

I'm currently trying to train my gluteus medius in order to provide a more stable stance while squatting. My knees feel kind of wobbly while doing such motions and I read that this would help.

To train this muscle, I do lateral leg raises while lying on my side. For each leg individually, in total I do 2-3 sets of about 10 reps 2 times a week, depending on how I feel that day. For my right leg, after a few reps I really feel my gluteus medius working and firing (the usual muscle burn you get when going to failure). However with my left leg, I don't feel my gluteus medius working at all, even not after 15 or 20 reps. I know it is likely that one side/leg is a little stronger than the other but this huge difference seems kind of unusal to me.

Also when performing the exercise with my left leg, I feel some sort of stretch in the back of my knee, which also extends towards the region of my hamstrings and calfs.

I'd also like to state that I'm doing the exercise motion exactly the same with both legs, which my training partner double checked too.

Now my question is, what can I do about this difference in the legs? Is this a normal thing to experience? I'd like to feel my gluteus medius working on both legs instead of feeling a stretch in the left one.

Answer (score -2):

The gluteus medius is a balance muscle, when you walk this muscle keeps you from falling, literally this is it's main job.

If your walking for is not correct, maybe you are wearing a bag on your side, the muscle on one side can become weaker than the other over time.

Comment: Thats not an answer at all. At best its a summary of my problem.